# Getting State of Modifier Keys Compact Framework

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

How can I get the state of a modifier key using VB.NET on the Compact Framework, in this case Windows Mobile 6.1. I want to be able to determine if the following keys are pressed or locked:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>
<kbd>ALT</kbd>

and for the Psion Teklogix machines
Orange
Blue
Although I may be able to work this out, if I can determine the others.

I want to create my own on-screen indicator panel and want to poll the keys, not using events.

Answer (score 0):

So there is the AllKeys function. Probably the best way to go today.

[just say no to GAPI – What you need to know about AllKeys and input management.](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2009/05/06/just-say-no-to-gapi-what-you-need-to-know-about-allkeys-and-input-management.aspx)

And this link should give you the P/Invoke to use in managed code.

[Capture all Windows Mobile device keys using the AllKeys API](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikefrancis/archive/2009/03/28/porting-gapi-keys-to-wm-6-1-and-6-5.aspx)